# How to use istream to read formatted input with empty field

Tags: c++, istream, formatted-input

I would like to read a file with specified format with std::istream or fscanf().

Each line of the file is consist of several fields. The fields may be a char, a float or a integer. Each field has fixed width and may be empty. Is there a way to stop std::istream from ignoring the empty fields?

=================================================================

The following is the detailed description.

I am writing an program parsing pdb-style files.
Part of the format follows the following format:
Record Format

```
COLUMNS        DATA  TYPE    FIELD        DEFINITION
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 -  6        Record name   "ATOM  "
 7 - 11        Integer       serial       Atom  serial number.
13 - 16        Atom          name         Atom name.
17             Character     altLoc       Alternate location indicator.
18 - 20        Residue name  resName      Residue name.
22             Character     chainID      Chain identifier.
23 - 26        Integer       resSeq       Residue sequence number.
27             AChar         iCode        Code for insertion of residues.
31 - 38        Real(8.3)     x            Orthogonal coordinates for X in Angstroms.
39 - 46        Real(8.3)     y            Orthogonal coordinates for Y in Angstroms.
47 - 54        Real(8.3)     z            Orthogonal coordinates for Z in Angstroms.
55 - 60        Real(6.2)     occupancy    Occupancy.
61 - 66        Real(6.2)     tempFactor   Temperature  factor.
77 - 78        LString(2)    element      Element symbol, right-justified.
79 - 80        LString(2)    charge       Charge  on the atom.
```

And here is part of the actual input:

```
ATOM      1  N   MET A   0      24.512   8.259  -9.688  1.00 33.83           N  
ATOM      2  CA  MET A   0      24.523   9.740  -9.865  1.00 32.90           C  
ATOM      3  C   MET A   0      25.889  10.228 -10.330  1.00 31.90           C  
ATOM      4  O   MET A   0      26.886   9.516 -10.198  1.00 32.07           O  
ATOM      5  CB  MET A   0      24.143  10.414  -8.560  1.00 34.34           C  
ATOM      6  CG  MET A   0      24.891   9.880  -7.378  1.00 35.66           C  
ATOM      7  SD  MET A   0      24.111  10.428  -5.871  1.00 38.66           S  
ATOM      8  CE  MET A   0      24.454  12.221  -5.988  1.00 36.36           C  
ATOM      9  N   VAL A   1      25.922  11.435 -10.891  1.00 30.10           N  
ATOM     10  CA  VAL A   1      27.161  12.020 -11.393  1.00 27.92           C  
ATOM     11  C   VAL A   1      27.260  13.522 -11.114  1.00 26.21           C  
ATOM     12  O   VAL A   1      26.304  14.278 -11.304  1.00 26.54           O  
ATOM     13  CB  VAL A   1      27.312  11.769 -12.919  1.00 27.99           C  
ATOM     14  CG1 VAL A   1      28.557  12.455 -13.466  1.00 27.68           C  
ATOM     15  CG2 VAL A   1      27.395  10.282 -13.189  1.00 28.05           C
```

As you may notice, some of the fields are empty. For example, altLoc(alternative location) at column 17 is optional, and charge at column 79-80 is usually missing.
Sometimes the fields are not separated, as the name, altLoc and resName field may form something like CG1AVAL, which is actually CG1, A and VAL.
I am trying to implement the program with C++. I tried both operator>> and fscanf but failed to find a solution to read the input into a struct Atom.

```
struct Atom
{
    std::string recordName{ 6 };
    int serial;
    std::string name{ 4 };
    char altLoc;
    std::string resName{ 3 };
    char chainID;
    int resSeq;
    char iCode;
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    double occupancy;
    double tempFactor;
    char segment;
    char element;
    char charge;
};
```

setw(size_t n) does not work as I expected, and since I have to dual with 41.9GB of input, performance is important, so I prefer not to add too much overhead like getline() the input in a string and then parse that string. Here is my failed attempt:

```
ChainReader & ChainReader::operator>>(Atom & atom)
{
    *stream //stream is a pointer to stream, which is a member of ChainReader
        >> std::setw(4) >> atom.recordName
        >> std::setw(7) >> atom.serial
        >> std::setw(5) >> atom.name
        >> std::setw(1) >> atom.altLoc
        >> std::setw(3) >> atom.resName
        >> std::setw(2) >> atom.chainID
        >> std::setw(4) >> atom.resSeq
        >> std::setw(1) >> atom.iCode
        >> std::setw(11) >> atom.x
        >> std::setw(8) >> atom.y
        >> std::setw(8) >> atom.z
        >> std::setw(6) >> atom.occupancy
        >> std::setw(6) >> atom.tempFactor
        >> std::setw(10) >> atom.segment
        >> std::setw(2) >> atom.element
        >> std::setw(2) >> atom.charge;
    return *this;
}
```

**Update:**

Come up with a solution with getline and string parsing. Works, still testing for performance.

```
ChainReader & ChainReader::operator>>(Atom & atom)
{
    std::string line;
    line.reserve(80);
    std::getline(*stream, line);
    atom.recordName = line.substr(0, 4);
    atom.serial = std::stoi(line.substr(6, 5));
    atom.name = line.substr(12, 4);
    atom.altLoc = line[16];
    atom.resName = line.substr(17, 3);
    atom.chainID = line[21];
    atom.resSeq = std::stoi(line.substr(22, 4));
    atom.iCode = line[26];
    atom.x = std::stod(line.substr(30, 8));
    atom.y = std::stod(line.substr(38, 8));
    atom.z = std::stod(line.substr(46, 8));
    atom.occupancy = std::stod(line.substr(54, 6));
    atom.tempFactor = std::stod(line.substr(60, 6));
    atom.segment = line[75];
    atom.element = line[77];
    atom.charge = line[79];
    return *this;
}
```

**Update 2:**
The program reads 276231 chains in ASTRAL data set and calculates dihedral angles along the chains. Takes totally 10237134 ms, or 3 hours. The data set is about 42GB, so the performance is totally acceptable.

Comment: What is your question? What have you done so far? Please reduce this to a [MCVE].. Study this: [ask]

Comment: `>>` is the wrong tool for the job. If your fields always appear in fixed character columns, then there's only one method that is guaranteed to give you that portion of each record: `substr()`. Use `std::getline()` to read your input, one record at a time, then use `substr()` to extract each field, and then trim off any trailing whitespace. Mission accomplished.

Comment: Ugh...fixed formatting.  I wonder if we could go back in time and slap our former selves for ever thinking fixed formatting was a good thing.

Comment: Performance will be great. All those substrings are under the short-string-optimization cutoff.